# How to import NPM package in vue 3 (Danfo.js)

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs3, danfojs

This seems like a novice question and yet I don't understand it. How do I import and use a third party js library in vue 3? In this case I'm trying to use Danfo.js https://danfo.jsdata.org/getting-started by doing `npm install danfojs` (even though it only shows to use cdn for browser use I think this is the same thing but correct me if wrong). Then idk if this is something that I import in each file I want to use or if I do it in main.js and it works globally automatically or what. I tried making main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import danfo from 'danfojs';

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(danfo)
app.mount('#app')
```

and then idk if that's correct but if so then how do I call dfd from inside the setup() of a component

```
function danfoTest(){
      console.log('idk', dfd)
      const json_data = [
        { A: 0.4612, B: 4.28283, C: -1.509, D: -1.1352 },
        { A: 0.5112, B: -0.22863, C: -3.39059, D: 1.1632 },
        { A: 0.6911, B: -0.82863, C: -1.5059, D: 2.1352 },
        { A: 0.4692, B: -1.28863, C: 4.5059, D: 4.1632 }]
                    
        const df = new dfd.DataFrame(json_data)
        console.log('here')
        df['A'].print()
    }
```

Idk if this is a lack of vue 3 understanding or lack of Danfo.js understanding but either way would appreciate some help, thanks!

Also is is possible can is only option? When adding the `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/danfojs@0.1.2/dist/index.min.js"></script>` tag to index.js it did work but I was getting errors in terminal about dfd not being defined although calling dfd did work. I assume because it loads the script later idk either way I think I want the npm install way and the `npm install danfojs-node` I believe is for a node version not the browser version which is why I did `npm install danfojs`

Answer (score 1):

While I am unsure myself. You are correct to assume that

```
npm install danfojs
```

is for the browser clients. I consume the library as follows -

```
import {DataFrame} from 'danfojs/dist/core/frame';
import {Series} from 'danfojs/dist/core/series';
```