# How to import and use Tensorflow's DANFO.js library inside an Angular web app?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tensorflow, danfojs

I am trying to use Tensorflow's [DANFO.js](https://danfo.jsdata.org/getting-started) library inside an `Angular web app` (with Ionic component's but that is irelevant).

- I simply ran the command: `npm install danfojs --save` and `npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node --save`
- I tried all kinds of imports inside an Angular `Service` like: `import 'danfojs';`, `import { DataFrame } from 'danfojs';` or even according to only [related question to this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64615588/how-to-import-npm-package-in-vue-3-danfo-js) I could find:`import  { DataFrame } from 'danfojs/dist/core/frame';`
- All of the above examples don't work
- I even tried importing the DANFO.js in `app.module` without any change

**And I always get this error message (rest of the error is in edit):**

```
Build at: 2021-11-21T21:38:12.984Z - Hash: 5f05ff4be188e54ccaaf - Time: 10137ms
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/core/generic.d.ts:75:26 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@tensorflow/tfjs-node' or its corresponding type declarations.    
[ng] 75     get tensor(): import("@tensorflow/tfjs-node").Tensor1D | import("@tensorflow/tfjs-node").Tensor2D;
[ng]                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/core/generic.d.ts:75:69 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@tensorflow/tfjs-node' or its corresponding type declarations.    
[ng] 75     get tensor(): import("@tensorflow/tfjs-node").Tensor1D | import("@tensorflow/tfjs-node").Tensor2D;
```

### How can I use DANFO.js inside an Angular app (specifically inside an service)?

---

**Edit:**

I added code to `tsconfig.js` according to the answer below, unfortunately the error persists. This is my `tsconfig.js` file:

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

The whole error code gets so long it doesn't fit VS Code terminal (there are just hundreds of errors):

```
[ng] 84     to_csv(options?: CsvOutputOptionsNode): string | void;
[ng]               ~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:84:20 - error TS1109: Expression expected.
[ng] 84     to_csv(options?: CsvOutputOptionsNode): string | void;
[ng]                       ~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:84:22 - error TS2693: 'CsvOutputOptionsNode' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
[ng] 84     to_csv(options?: CsvOutputOptionsNode): string | void;
[ng]                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:84:43 - error TS1005: ';' expected.
[ng] 84     to_csv(options?: CsvOutputOptionsNode): string | void;
[ng]                                              ~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:84:45 - error TS2693: 'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
[ng] 84     to_csv(options?: CsvOutputOptionsNode): string | void;
[ng]                                                ~~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:84:54 - error TS2532: Object 
is possibly 'undefined'.
[ng] 84     to_csv(options?: CsvOutputOptionsNode): string | void;
[ng]                                                         ~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:84:58 - error TS1109: Expression expected.
[ng] 84     to_csv(options?: CsvOutputOptionsNode): string | void;
[ng]                                                             ~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:85:5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'to_json'.
[ng] 85     to_json(options?: {
[ng]        ~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:85:13 - error TS2304: Cannot 
find name 'options'.
[ng] 85     to_json(options?: {
[ng]                ~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:85:21 - error TS1109: Expression expected.
[ng] 85     to_json(options?: {
[ng]                        ~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:86:18 - error TS2362: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
[ng] 86         format?: "row" | "column";
[ng]                     ~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:86:26 - error TS2363: The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
[ng] 86         format?: "row" | "column";
[ng]                             ~~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:86:34 - error TS1005: ',' expected.
[ng] 86         format?: "row" | "column";
[ng]                                     ~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:87:20 - error TS2693: 'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
[ng] 87         filePath?: string;
[ng]                       ~~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:87:26 - error TS1005: ',' expected.
[ng] 87         filePath?: string;
[ng]                             ~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:88:7 - error TS1005: ';' expected.
[ng] 88     }): object | void;
[ng]          ~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:88:9 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'object'.
[ng] 88     }): object | void;
[ng]            ~~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:88:18 - error TS2532: Object 
is possibly 'undefined'.
[ng] 88     }): object | void;
[ng]                     ~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:88:22 - error TS1109: Expression expected.
[ng] 88     }): object | void;
[ng]                         ~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:89:5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'to_excel'.
[ng] 89     to_excel(options?: {
[ng]        ~~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:89:14 - error TS2304: Cannot 
find name 'options'.
[ng] 89     to_excel(options?: {
[ng]                 ~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:89:22 - error TS1109: Expression expected.
[ng] 89     to_excel(options?: {
[ng]                         ~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:90:20 - error TS2693: 'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
[ng] 90         filePath?: string;
[ng]                       ~~~~~~
[ng] Error: 6mnode_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:90:26 - error TS1005: ',' expected.
[ng] 90         filePath?: string;
[ng]                             ~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:91:21 - error TS2693: 'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
[ng] 91         sheetName?: string;
[ng]                        ~~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:91:27 - error TS1005: ',' expected.
[ng] 91         sheetName?: string;
[ng]                              ~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:92:7 - error TS1005: ';' expected.
[ng] 92     }): void;
[ng]          ~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:92:13 - error TS1109: Expression expected.
[ng] 92     }): void;
[ng]                ~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:93:12 - error TS1005: ';' expected.
[ng] 93     print(): void;
[ng]               ~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:93:18 - error TS1109: Expression expected.
[ng] 93     print(): void;
[ng]                     ~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:94:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
[ng] 94 }
[ng]    ~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:201:5 - error TS1131: Property or signature expected.
[ng] 201     get dtype(): string;
[ng]         ~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:201:5 - error TS2304: Cannot 
find name 'get'.
[ng] 201     get dtype(): string;
[ng]         ~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:201:9 - error TS1005: ';' expected.
[ng] 201     get dtype(): string;
[ng]             ~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:201:9 - error TS2304: Cannot 
find name 'dtype'.
[ng] 201     get dtype(): string;
[ng]             ~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:201:16 - error TS1005: ';' expected.
[ng] 201     get dtype(): string;
[ng]                    ~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:201:18 - error TS2693: 'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
[ng] 201     get dtype(): string;
[ng]                      ~~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:202:5 - error TS2304: Cannot 
find name 'drop_duplicates'.
[ng] 202     drop_duplicates(options?: {
[ng]         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:202:21 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'options'.
[ng] 202     drop_duplicates(options?: {
[ng]                         ~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:202:29 - error TS1109: Expression expected.
[ng] 202     drop_duplicates(options?: {
[ng]                                 ~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:203:16 - error TS2362: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
[ng] 203         keep?: "first" | "last";
[ng]                    ~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:203:26 - error TS2363: The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or 
an enum type.
[ng] 203         keep?: "first" | "last";
[ng]                              ~~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:203:32 - error TS1005: ',' expected.
[ng] 203         keep?: "first" | "last";
[ng]                                    ~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:204:19 - error TS2693: 'boolean' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
[ng] 204         inplace?: boolean;
[ng]                       ~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:204:26 - error TS1005: ',' expected.
[ng] 204         inplace?: boolean;
[ng]                              ~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:205:7 - error TS1005: ';' expected.
[ng] 205     }): Series | void;
[ng]           ~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:205:9 - error TS2362: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
[ng] 205     }): Series | void;
[ng]             ~~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:205:18 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
[ng] 205     }): Series | void;
[ng]                      ~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:205:22 - error TS1109: Expression expected.
[ng] 205     }): Series | void;
[ng]                          ~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:206:5 - error TS2304: Cannot 
find name 'astype'.
[ng] 206     astype(dtype: "float32" | "int32" | "string" | "boolean", options?: {    
[ng]         ~~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:206:12 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'dtype'.
[ng] 206     astype(dtype: "float32" | "int32" | "string" | "boolean", options?: {    
[ng]                ~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:206:17 - error TS1005: ',' expected.
[ng] 206     astype(dtype: "float32" | "int32" | "string" | "boolean", options?: {    
[ng]                     ~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:206:19 - error TS2362: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
[ng] 206     astype(dtype: "float32" | "int32" | "string" | "boolean", options?: {    
[ng]                       ~~~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:206:31 - error TS2363: The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or 
an enum type.
[ng] 206     astype(dtype: "float32" | "int32" | "string" | "boolean", options?: {
[ng]                                   ~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:206:41 - error TS2363: The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or 
an enum type.
[ng] 206     astype(dtype: "float32" | "int32" | "string" | "boolean", options?: {
[ng]                                             ~~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:206:52 - error TS2363: The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or 
an enum type.
[ng] 206     astype(dtype: "float32" | "int32" | "string" | "boolean", options?: {
[ng]                                                        ~~~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:206:63 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'options'.
[ng] 206     astype(dtype: "float32" | "int32" | "string" | "boolean", options?: {    
[ng]                                                                   ~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:206:71 - error TS1109: Expression expected.
[ng] 206     astype(dtype: "float32" | "int32" | "string" | "boolean", options?: {    
[ng]                                                                           ~      
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:207:19 - error TS2693: 'boolean' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
[ng] 207         inplace?: boolean;
[ng]                       ~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:207:26 - error TS1005: ',' expected.
[ng] 207         inplace?: boolean;
[ng]                              ~
[ng] Error: node_modules/danfojs/types/shared/types.d.ts:208:7 - error TS1005: ';' expected.
[ng] 208     }): Series | void;
```

Comment: you will have to install `@tensorflow/tfjs-node` as well. check here, https://danfo.jsdata.org/getting-started#creating-a-dataframe-series

Comment: Even after installing the `@tensorflow/tfjs-node` the problem still persists.

Comment: I am sorry but I couldn't find any reference (in link you provided) that stated I needed to install `@tensorflow/tfjs-node`. @Piyush Jain

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Tested on MacOS and Windows 10

#### Try the following steps to install and use `danfojs` combined with `angular`:

1. Create new angular app with `ng new danfojs-app`
2. `cd danfojs-app`
3. `npm install danfojs`
4. `npm install jquery` <-- Optional. The demo runs without it too.
5. Add `"scripts": ["./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"]` to `angular.json` <-- Optional.

angular.json

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "danfojs-app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/danfojs-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": ["./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"] 
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "danfojs-app:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "danfojs-app:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "danfojs-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "danfojs-app"
}
```

6. Add `"skipLibCheck": true` to `tsconfig.json`, which will prevent Typescript from type-checking all the imported libraries:

```json
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

7. Make sure `app.component.ts` looks like this (The `jquery` part is optional and can be omitted):

```json
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;
import * as dfd from "danfojs";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'A danfojs test';

  public ngOnInit()
  {
    $(document).ready(function(){

        const df = new dfd.DataFrame(
        { pig: [20, 18, 489, 675, 1776], horse: [4, 25, 281, 600, 1900] },
        { index: [1990, 1997, 2003, 2009, 2014] }
      );
      df.head().print()
      const s = new dfd.Series([1, 3, 2, 6, 10, 34, 40, 51, 90, 75]);
      s.print()

    });
  }
}
```

8. Make sure `app.component.html` looks like this:

```html
<div class="content" role="main">
<span>{{ title }} app is running!</span>
</div>
```

9. Run `ng serve`

And then you should get a result like this after navigating to localhost:4200 in your browser:

[image]

#### Using `Plotly` with `danfojs`

If you also want to use `Plotly` to visualize things, then change `index.html` like this:

```
!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>DanfojsApp</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-1.58.4.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Change `app.component.html` like this:

```
<div class="content" role="main">
<span>{{ title }} app is running!</span>
<div id="plot_div"></div>
</div>
```

and finally change `app.component.ts` like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;
import * as dfd from "danfojs";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'A danfojs test';

  public ngOnInit()
  {
    $(document).ready(function(){

        const df = new dfd.DataFrame(
        { pig: [20, 18, 489, 675, 1776], horse: [4, 25, 281, 600, 1900] },
        { index: [1990, 1997, 2003, 2009, 2014] }
      );
      df.head().print()
      const s = new dfd.Series([1, 3, 2, 6, 10, 34, 40, 51, 90, 75]);
      s.print()
      df['plot']("plot_div").line()
    });
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Versions on MacOS:

```
Angular CLI: 13.0.3
Node: 16.10.0
Package Manager: npm 8.1.4
OS: darwin x64
Danfojs: 0.3.3
Plotly: 1.58.4
```

Versions on Windows 10:

```
Angular CLI: 13.0.3
Node: 16.13.0
Package Manager: npm 8.1.4
OS: win32 x64
Danfojs: 0.3.3
Plotly: 1.58.4
```

Comment: Do I need to install the jquery also? Isn't just setting the typecheking to `false` enough?

Comment: Ah yes  I'am sorry my bad - I want to use all your steps except the `jquery`. I will try it ASAP :)

Comment: Hi unfortunately the error is still there (TS is throwing hundreds of errors on each line of the DANFO.js library). I updated my question please take a look.

Comment: Did you follow the steps 1 to 9?

Comment: Yes I created a brand new project and followed 1-9 (except the jquery parts). Maybe I have some bad versions (will check out).

Comment: I just confirmed that the solution works both on MacOS and Windows 10.

Comment: + i get errors running NG build also (same errors as when serving the project). It seems like angular is ignoring the `"skipLibCheck": true` setting ...

Comment: Even with `npm start --reset-cache` error still persists ... It changed the color of errors but still can't compile.

Comment: Not sure how to help.. as I said it’s working on Windows 10 and MacOS for me..I listed all the versions at the bottom of the answer. Maybe you have some global settings set in VS code.